# CSS Keyframe Animation Not Working in Mozilla

Tags: css, animation, mozilla

I am trying to make 2 background images fade, and while working correctly in Chrome/Safari, I'm having no luck with Firefox.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
animation: slides 20s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: slides 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: slides 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: slides 20s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: slides 20s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes slides {
  from {
        -moz-background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");

    -moz-background-size: cover;
    }
60% {
        -moz-background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background2.jpg");

    -moz-background-size: cover;
    }

    to {
        -moz-background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");

    -moz-background-size: cover;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slides {
    from {
        background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }
60% {
        background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background2.jpg");
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }

    to {
        background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }
}

@keyframes slides {
 from {
        background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
    }
60% {
        background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
    }

    to {
        background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

I've tried having the CSS inline and linking to an external stylesheet but neither have worked. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should also post the HTML and make a demo to show the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Animating background images does not work cross browser, so I suggest you use a pseudo to achieve that.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

html::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-image: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background2.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: slides 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: slides 20s linear infinite;
  animation: slides 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slides {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slides {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes slides {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

div.container {
  position: relative;           /*  needed on all direct children  */
  background: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This content is not affected by the background animation
</div>
```

Comment: This does work to an extent, but the entire page content is fading with the background images now. How can it be applied to the background only? Thanks

Comment: @user974254 One use the `::before` pseudo instead ... updated my answer

Comment: Note that the only [prefix that is required (and then only *barely*)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) is `-webkit-`. `-ms-` and `-o-` don't even seem to exist for keyframes or animation.

Comment: @misterManSam Thanks, so very right ... simply copied OP's rule .. updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [`autoprefixer`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/), add only the un-prefixed code in the left panel and, for maximum browser compatibility, add `> 0%` in the tiny settings box in the bottom part of the page.

The result:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes slides {
from {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
    }

60% {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
   }

to {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
   }
}
@-moz-keyframes slides {
from {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
  -moz-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
    }

60% {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background2.jpg");
  -moz-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
   }

to {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
  -moz-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
   }
}
@-o-keyframes slides {
from {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
  -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
    }

60% {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background2.jpg");
  -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
   }

to {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
  -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
   }
}
@keyframes slides {
from {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
  -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
    }

60% {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background2.jpg");
  -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
   }

to {
  background: url("http://web178.ocean.studiocoast.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Background1.jpg");
  -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
   }
}
```

Comment: Since `background-image` is not an animatable property (it does work on Chrome/Safari though), this answer will not solve the question as this won't work in Firefox